# Get value from ColumnA if rest of row contains (value)

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table with unique image names in Column A, followed by (a different # of) tags in Columns B,C,D,etc.

```
Target  R  Tags     
AF-204  A  one  portrait  cute
AF-205  A  cute
AF-206  A  portrait  woman  cute
AF-207  A  portrait  people
AF-208  A  portrait  facial  cute
AF-209  A  cute  portrait  woman
AF-210  A  cute  portrait
AF-211  A  portrait  people  one
```

I'm trying to write a formula that would allow me to

1. check if a certain tag (let's say "cute") appears in a row
2. get the label (i.e. value in column A of that row)

I have a list of unique tags within this dataset & # of times they appear on a separate sheet.

I would like these labels to be listed, and I'm flexible about doing it vertically or horizontally - I just can't figure it out. I've tried H/VLOOKUP, INDEX, SEARCH, and similar functions. Please help? I searched for this question extensively as well, but I can't find an answer. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to return the value in column A, this could be one approach.

Place the formula in example column `H2` and drag down from row 2 to row x.

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(A2:E2;"cute")>0,A2,"Not Found"),"")
```

The `COUNTIF` looks for the word "cute" in only on row. If the word is found, it will return 1 (so the statement will be TRUE). Then the IF formula return the value in A2. Otherwise it will return "Not Found".

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!